# Understanding how to shift Square root functions: $y=-\sqrt{4-x}$

Tags: calculus

Graph: $y=-\sqrt{4-x}$

I was wondering what does the $4$ indicate?

Does it merely mean move the intercept to $-4$ on the $x$ axis?

Also, does the -$x$ mean to flip the root function on the $y$ axis?

Am I correct?

The positioning of the terms are different from what is stated in the textbook, thus, the reason for my question.

Comment: I think you need some brackets; do you mean $\sqrt{4-x}$ or $\sqrt{4}-x$?

Comment: Note that the zero is at $x=4$, not $x=-4$. Otherwise your reasoning seems fine! To get the graph start with $\sqrt{x}$. Flip it around the $y$ axis and move it such that the zero of the graph is at $x=4$.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: I understand that a intercept , 0 is at 4 but I am asking how one would perform transformations with the available information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=-\sqrt{4-x}=-\sqrt{-(x-4)}$ The minus on the outside of the square root  is a reflection in the x-axis while the minus on the inside of the square root is a reflection in the y-axis. The -4 gives the graph a shift 4 units to the right. QED

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/grapher/exports/0rsvnz3wzp.png

Comment: How come when I plug the function into a graph calculator I receive a different answer?

Comment: Forget it I see my error. I first must reflect on the x axis and then reflect on the y axis. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Cetshwayo Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

In the function $$y = \sqrt{4-x}$$

The $4$ indicates that the parent function is $\sqrt{-x}$, and it is translated $4$ units to the left.

The $-x$ indicates that the parent function is $\sqrt{x}$ and is flipped over the y-axis.

So yes, you are correct.

Comment: Wouldn't that be towards the left? As in -4?

Comment: @Cetshwayo ahh my bad. I meant to say that, but I messed up. I'll change it.